# Retrieving data from website with password

Tags: html, vba, excel

I'm new to asking questions on this site, but have used it to research VBA questions I've had.  I've used this site for the current project I'm working on, which includes going to a website, logging in and then going to a different page to extract information and pasted it into excel.  I'm having issues getting the information in a readable format.  I can't post images, so I'm just including some of the html code from the website

```
<tr class="info">
    <td class="print-hide"><input type="checkbox" value="Check All" onClick="this.value=setAll(this.form.LNList)"></td>     
    <td><a href="showLN.cfm?DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA&SortOrder=LN">LN</a></td>
    <td><a href="showLN.cfm?DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA&SortOrder=Typ">Typ</a></td>
    <td><a href="showLN.cfm?DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA&SortOrder=STAT">Stat</a></td>
    <td class="print-hide"><a href="showLN.cfm?DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA&SortOrder=PhotoCount">Photos</a></td>
    <td class="print-hide"><a href="showLN.cfm?DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA&SortOrder=HasVT">VT</a></td>
    <td><a href="showLN.cfm?DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA&SortOrder=STRT">Address</a></td>

    <td><a href="showLN.cfm?DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA&SortOrder=CITY">City</a></td>
    <td><a href="showLN.cfm?DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA&SortOrder=CNTY">County</a></td>
    <td><a href="showLN.cfm?DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA&SortOrder=AR">Area</a></td>
    <td class="print-hide">Map</td>
    <td class="print-hide">Tax</td>
    <td><a href="showLN.cfm?DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA&SortOrder=SQFT_TOT">SQFT</a></td>
    <td><a href="showLN.cfm?DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA&SortOrder=LPPerSQFT">LP/SQFT</a></td>
    <td><a href="showLN.cfm?DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA&SortOrder=TOT_ACRES">Acres</a></td>
    <td><a href="showLN.cfm?DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA&SortOrder=BR">BR</a></td>
    <td><a href="showLN.cfm?DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA&SortOrder=BAF">BAF</a></td>
    <td><a href="showLN.cfm?DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA&SortOrder=BAH">BAH</a></td>
    <td><a href="showLN.cfm?DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA&SortOrder=SUBD">SUBD</a></td>
    <td class="print-hide"><a href="showLN.cfm?DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA&SortOrder=LB">LB</a></td>
    <td><a href="showLN.cfm?DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA&SortOrder=LP">LP</a></td>
    <td><a href="showLN.cfm?DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA&SortOrder=SP">SP</a></td>
    <td><a href="showLN.cfm?DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA&SortOrder=LD">LD</a></td>
    <td><a href="showLN.cfm?DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA&SortOrder=CLD">CLD</a></td>
    <td><a href="showLN.cfm?DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA&SortOrder=DOM">DOM</a></td>
</tr>

    <tr valign="middle" class="odd">
        <td class="print-hide"><input type="Checkbox" name="LNList" value="7458475">

        <td><a href="propertyDetail.cfm?TYP=SF&LN=7458475" target="PropertyDetail">7458475</a></td>
        <td>SFD</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td class="print-hide"><a href="javascript:openpopup900('showphotos.cfm?TYP=SFD&LN=7458475')"><img border="0" src="http://www.gamls.com/images/icons/camera.gif"></a> 7</td>
        <td class="print-hide">--</td>
        <td>3833 Bouldercrest Rd</td>

        <td>Ellenwood</td>
        <td>DeKalb</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td class="print-hide"><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=33.656189,+-84.286171+(3833+Bouldercrest%20Rd+Ellenwood+30294)&iwloc=A&hl=en" target="NewMap"><img border="0" src="http://www.gamls.com/images/icons/map.png"></a></td>

        <td class="print-hide">

            <a href="http://www.gamls.com/secure/CRS_SSO.cfm?Srvc=rpt&CNTY=DeKalb&TID=15%20023%2004%20017&STN=3833&STRT=Bouldercrest%20Rd" target="ToolWindow">View</a>

        </td>
        <td>1,390</td>
        <td>$143</td>
        <td>4.200</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>None</td>
        <td class="print-hide"><a href="http://www.gamls.com/secure/membership/index.cfm?Typ=Office&Fn=Office&OfficeID=RESU01">RESU01</a></td>
        <td><span style="color:red;">$199,000</span></td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>05/21/2015</td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>112</td>
    </tr>

    <tr valign="middle" class="even">
        <td class="print-hide"><input type="Checkbox" name="LNList" value="7458539">

        <td><a href="propertyDetail.cfm?TYP=SF&LN=7458539" target="PropertyDetail">7458539</a></td>
        <td>SFD</td>
        <td>A</td>
        <td class="print-hide"><a href="javascript:openpopup900('showphotos.cfm?TYP=SFD&LN=7458539')"><img border="0" src="http://www.gamls.com/images/icons/camera.gif"></a> 13</td>
        <td class="print-hide">--</td>
        <td>3803 Bouldercrest Rd</td>

        <td>Ellenwood</td>
        <td>DeKalb</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td class="print-hide"><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=33.658211,+-84.287117+(3803+Bouldercrest%20Rd+Ellenwood+30294)&iwloc=A&hl=en" target="NewMap"><img border="0" src="http://www.gamls.com/images/icons/map.png"></a></td>

        <td class="print-hide">

            <a href="http://www.gamls.com/secure/CRS_SSO.cfm?Srvc=rpt&CNTY=DeKalb&TID=15%20023%2004%20003&STN=3803&STRT=Bouldercrest%20Rd" target="ToolWindow">View</a>

        </td>
        <td>1,495</td>
        <td>$133</td>
        <td>1.100</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>None</td>
        <td class="print-hide"><a href="http://www.gamls.com/secure/membership/index.cfm?Typ=Office&Fn=Office&OfficeID=RESU01">RESU01</a></td>
        <td><span style="color:red;">$199,000</span></td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>05/21/2015</td>
        <td>--</td>
        <td>112</td>
    </tr>
```

Here is my code:

```
Sub Get_GA_MLS_Help()

    Dim ieDoc As Object
    Dim j As Long


    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        'Navigate to main page to login
        .Navigate "http://www.gamls.com/"
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        'Enter username and password and then submit to login
        .Document.all.Item("username").Value = "UserName"
        .Document.all.Item("password").Value = "Pwd"
        .Document.forms(0).submit
    End With

    'Wait for main page to load
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)

    'Navigate to page with results that need to be exproted to Excel
    ie.Navigate "http://www.gamls.com/secure/search/showLN.cfm?DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA"
    'Wait for page with data to load
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10)

     Set ieDoc = ie.Document
     'Find table with the information for download
     Set Elements = ieDoc.getElementsByClassName("table table-condensed table-striped table-hover smText")


     For Each Element In Elements

        j = 0
        For Each Erow In Element.Rows
          Sheet1.Cells(j + 1, 1).Value = Erow.innertext
          j = j + 1
        Next Erow

    Next Element

End Sub
```

Here is what is being written to Excel:

> LNTypStatPhotosVTAddressCityCountyAreaMapTaxSQFTLP/SQFTAcresBRBAFBAHSUBDLBLPSPLD‌​CLDDOM
>   7458475SFDA 7--3833 Bouldercrest RdEllenwoodDeKalb43View
>   1,390$1434.200310NoneRESU01$199,000--05/21/2015--112 7458539SFDA
>   13--3803 Bouldercrest RdEllenwoodDeKalb43View
>   1,495$1331.100210NoneRESU01$199,000--05/21/2015--112 7423053SFDA
>   1--4600 Snapfinger RdEllenwoodDeKalb43View
>   1,040$1883.000210NonePHPA01$195,000--03/16/2015--178

Each row in the table just pastes in one cell instead of multiple columns and has no delimiters. I also tried using:

```
 With      ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;http://www.gamls.com/secure/search/     showLN.cfm?    DspFmt=1&Srch=1&TYP=SFD&ZIPLIST=30294&MINSQFT_TOT=1000&MAXSQFT_TOT=2000&STATLIST=A,N,I,RD,B,CK,PA", _
 Destination:=Range("a5"))

 .Name = "q?s=goog_2"
 .FieldNames = True
 .RowNumbers = False
 .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
 .PreserveFormatting = True
 .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
 .BackgroundQuery = True
 .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
 .SavePassword = False
 .SaveData = True
 .AdjustColumnWidth = True
 .RefreshPeriod = 0
 .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
 .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
 .WebTables = "1,2"
 .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
 .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
 .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
 .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
 .WebDisableRedirections = False
 .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

That code didn't paste anything into Excel.

The problem I'm having is the data get's placed in my workbook, but it's unreadable because it puts the full row together with no delimiters.

Comment: Is it not putting each value in separate columns? Please show example of current output and an example of desired output.

Comment: Sorry.  Here's what I'm getting in excel: LNTypStatPhotosVTAddressCityCountyAreaMapTaxSQFTLP/SQFTAcresBRBAFBAHSUBDLBLPSPLDCLDDOM
 7458475SFDA 7--3833 Bouldercrest RdEllenwoodDeKalb43View 1,390$1434.200310NoneRESU01$199,000--05/21/2015--112
 7458539SFDA 13--3803 Bouldercrest RdEllenwoodDeKalb43View 1,495$1331.100210NoneRESU01$199,000--05/21/2015--112
 7423053SFDA 1--4600 Snapfinger RdEllenwoodDeKalb43View 1,040$1883.000210NonePHPA01$195,000--03/16/2015--178
 I can't post pictures yet, but each row in the table just pastes in one cell instead of multiple columns and has no delimiters.

Comment: Also, my loop wasn't working for the elements, so I'm just printing row by row and then I'll figure out the rest.    Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value = Element.Children(0).Children(0).innertext
       Sheet1.Cells(2, 1).Value = Element.Children(0).Children(1).innertext
       Sheet1.Cells(3, 1).Value = Element.Children(0).Children(2).innertext
       Sheet1.Cells(4, 1).Value = Element.Children(0).Children(3).innertext
       Sheet1.Cells(5, 1).Value = Element.Children(0).Children(4).innertext
       Sheet1.Cells(6, 1).Value = Element.Children(0).Children(5).innertext

Comment: I edited your post to include the output. That is what is best for you to do when somebody asked you to include something.  As you can see it is not good in the comments.